How do I merge data from one MongoDB database to another
I have two MongoDB databases. Initially, both databases serve different audiences, but similar application / project.
Application A ==> MongoDB database A
Application B ==> MongoDB database B
Now, I want to merge the two audiences to use only Application A with MongoDB database A.
Now, the issue is: MongoDB database B already contains data. I want users in MongoDB database B to use Application A with their data intact.
How do I go about this and would there be any cons merging both audiences?
Thank you in advance.

$merge could be what you are looking for. But at the current status of the question, the scope is far larger than the scope that a single SO question should contain. Be more precise on the topic and provide a [mre].

Merging is trivial - append each collection on dbA with data from the same collection on dbB. The real question is how are you going to resolve conflicts.
